# How correctly filter column with data separated by a comma?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Let's say I have such DataFrame.

```
+-----------+
|amount     |
+-----------+
|100,200,300|
|73         |
|56,89      |
+-----------+
```

Also, I have an array with numbers: `var array = Array(200, 73)`.

I want to filter this DataFrame by the array and take such a result:

```
+-----------+
|amount     |
+-----------+
|100,200,300|
|73         |
+-----------+
```

I used such code but it doesn't work the way I thought it would

```
df.filter(col("amount").isin(array: _*))
```

My next code returns such a result:

```
+-----------+
|amount     |
+-----------+
|73         |
+-----------+
```

What's wrong I did?

Comment: Can you share the schema of your Dataframe?

Comment: Well, the data type of the `amount` column is `StringType`.

Answer (score 3):

`split` the column into array of strings, `intersect` with a literal column of values you need to filter, and then check whether the result size is larger than zero:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("100,200,300", "73", "56,89")).toDF("amount")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [amount: string]

val array = Array("200", "73")
// array: Array[String] = Array(200, 73)

df.filter(size(array_intersect(split($"amount", ","), lit(array))) > 0).show
+-----------+
|     amount|
+-----------+
|100,200,300|
|         73|
+-----------+
```

Comment: What kind of import do you use for `array_intersect`? I tried to use such import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` but it cannot resolve the symbol array_intersect.

Comment: You should mention that `array_intersect` is only available for Spark 2.4+

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, I use `Spark 2.3.3`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can not use Spark 2.4, here is another way using [`array_contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains) and [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) functions.

First split the column `amount` to get array column:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("amount_array", split($"amount", ","))
```

Then filter using this filter expression:

```
val filterExpr = array.map(v => array_contains($"amount_array", v)).reduce(_ or _)

df2.filter(filterExpr).drop("amount_array").show()

//+-----------+
//|     amount|
//+-----------+
//|100,200,300|
//|         73|
//+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The [isin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isin(list:Any*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) method, compare the exact version of left hand side string with array of values in right side. The issue in your case is, it tried to compare the string "100,200,300" with string "200", obviously it won't match.

One way of solving the issue is to explode the string column split by comma and then do apply the isin method on the exploded column it will work.

```
df.withColumn("exploded", explode(split(col("amount"), ",")))
.filter(col("exploded").isin(array: _*))
.drop(col("exploded"))
.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can the name `exploded` be the same as the original column name `amount`? I don't want to produce columns.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek You can drop the exploded column and continue with your existing column. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Spark 2.4+, use array functions like `array_intersect`, otherwise use UDF:

```
val containsStr = udf((data:String) => data.split(",").exists(array.contains))

df
  .where(containsStr($"amount"))
  .show()
```